# JFreeChart x axis Format

Tags: jfreechart, axis-labels

How to format x axis labels? 
I have a chart(look at attach1)
[image: attache1]
I need to change x axis labels to the labels in the next attach (but with the same chart)
[image: attach2]

Answer (score 3):

To set the label of the axis (in your example "counts") call

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.getDomainAxis().setLabel("counts");
```

To change the number format of the axis call

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
((NumberAxis)plot.getDomainAxis()).setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("0"));
```

To change the visible range of the plot call

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
((NumberAxis)plot.getDomainAxis()).setRange(0,20);
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!