# Change JFreeChart X & Y Axis Labels at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am searching for the commands to change the String for X and Y Axis at runtime. I have language menu on my gui. As soon as the button for a specific language is pressed I invoke following methods:

```
public void resetLanguage(Locale locale)
{
    displayLanguage = locale;
    resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("DTTUI-Text", displayLanguage);

    chart.setTitle(resources.getString("GUI_CHART_TITLE"));
    measurement.setDescription(resources.getString("GUI_CHART_GRAPH_NAME"));
}
```

chart is a JFreeChart and measurement is a XYSeries. Anyone knows how to find the setter methods for the axis labels? Thanks in advance!

I created my chart like this:

```
    XYSeriesCollection collection = new XYSeriesCollection();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Title");
    series.add(0, 0);
    series.add(10,10);
    collection.addSeries(series);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Title", "x",
            "y", collection);
```

Comment: `Axis#setLabel()`?

Comment: I dont understand what u mean.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26108850/261156)?